# Navigation problems with DIVs using Javascript. Project built using VS2013 and VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, devexpress

Hey I was looking for some help as I have a problem with my navigation on my application. Basically the site is split up into Divs and there is a save/next button that should take the user onto the next Div (screen). The client side event is JavaScript. The problem is that the whole application appear on the screen when I click the button instead of just the single screen. Could someone advise on how to hide the other Divs so only the current one is shown. My main div is called divOverview then my next screen is called divContactDetails then etc etc for another 9 screen(divs). Thanks

```
     <dx:LayoutItem ColSpan="1" ShowCaption="False">
            <LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
                <dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer runat="server" Width="100%">
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Text="Save/Next" Theme="Office2010Blue" OnClick="btnSave_Click">
                        <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s,e) {javascript:showonlyonev2('divContactDetails');}" />
                    </dx:ASPxButton>
                </dx:LayoutItemNestedControlContainer>
            </LayoutItemNestedControlCollection>
        </dx:LayoutItem>
```

The on_click with the save button here is the VB code behind

```
        If FocusSet = True Then
            ErrDetails.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            ErrDetails.Height = 20 * errCount
            ' Show the Overview screen at the beginning
            If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("showonlyonev2")) Then
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript _
                (Me.GetType(), "showonlyonev2", "showonlyonev2('divContactDetails');", True)
            End If
            If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("showonlyonev2")) Then
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript _
                (Me.GetType(), "showonlyonev2", "showonlyonev2('divContactDetails');", True)
            End If
            Return
        End If
```

JavaScript code(edit):

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
    function showonlyonev2(thechosenone) {
        var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var x = 0; x < newboxes.length; x++) {
            name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
            if (name == 'newboxes-2') {
                if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                    if (newboxes[x].style.display == 'block') {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                    }
                } else {
                    newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the `showonlyonev2` script look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the visibility issue. I simple removed the second part of the VB code.....

```
        If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("showonlyonev2")) Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript _
            (Me.GetType(), "showonlyonev2", "showonlyonev2('divContactDetails');", True)
        End If
        Return
    End If
```

Now the navigation is better but now getting Null References on other code. The joys of programming!